# Setting a Worksheet using both the worksheet name as defined in the object explorer with the workbook definition

Tags: excel, vba

So there are a few ways to set a worksheet in Excel.

```
set WS = Sheets("Name Here!")
set WS = WB.Sheets("Name Here!")
set WS = shNameOfTheSheetObject
```

However, there doesn't seem to be a way to do:

```
set WS = WB.shNameOfTheSheetObject
```

I'd like to know how, if it's possible, I can get this type of reference to work. I like being very, very explicit with my code (Perhaps too much so), and it'd be useful to know if I have multiple workbooks open that I'm handling.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but would guess that the problem is that `shNameOfTheSheetObject` is not a property of `WB`.  VB probably shims up the reference between `WS = shName...` and your sheet in the background

Comment: You're missing the `Set ...` part of setting an object.

Comment: Use the code name, not the worksheet name.  Then you can just access it directly:  `SheetCodeName` without any qualifier is all you need assuming you're in the same project.  If you're in a different project, it would be `ProjectCodeName.SheetCodeName`.

Comment: @Comintern: I am using the code name, and that's what I'm trying to solve - how to use ProjectCodeName.SheetCodeName, but WITH using the qualifier. As I mentioned, I like over-building my code. If you know how to self-reference the ProjectCodeName, that + the second part of your comment would be enough for the answer I'm looking for

Comment: @VincentG: Sure, I'm just writing a quick and dirty example

Comment: What do you mean by "self reference"? When then project is loaded it's implicitly in scope within that project. The worksheet document objects belong to the project, not the workbook.

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.VBProject` is a reference to the project. And you can browse  `ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents` collection to get the sheets?

Comment: It might help if you provide a somewhat _less_ minimal example of what you're doing. Maybe include the `Dim` statements and the assignment of `shNameOfTheSheetObject`.

Comment: FWIW if you like being very, very explicit, you'll want to use the `Worksheets` collection (which returns a `Worksheets` object - hint: worksheets are *items* of that collection object, not *members*), instead of the `Sheets` collection - `Sheets` includes `Chart` and about half a dozen other sheet types, not just `Worksheet` objects. The "code name" of a sheet is a *project*-scoped identifier, not a member of the `Workbook` it's defined in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a slight confusion on how the access via the code name works. When you get a worksheet via `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetName")` you query a collection on the workbook; when you use the code name, you get the corresponding component of the VBA project containing your project, which implements the `Worksheet` interface.

Both are the same object, but the resolution of the identifier takes a different path: a workbook does not know about the VBA components. Consequently, as @Comintern mentioned in the comments, you can only use the project name of the containing VBA project as further qualifier. That name is whatever you set it to via the project properties dialog. If you do not change it, it will always be `VBAProject` in Excel, which is not very helpful.

Comment: A quick expansion - Selecting the highest-level object is where you can see and edit the VBAProject Name